# How to connect phone to laptop via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my phone to Android Studio on my laptop, but I just can't figure it out. Is there a simple way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Make sure you install **Google USB Driver** and also your **Android Phone USB Driver**.

Step 2. Connect your Android phone, **Allow USB Debugging** (just tap **OK**).

Step 3. **Run** your application and **choose your Android Phone**.